# imagebutton onclientclick and onclick events

Tags: asp.net, events, onclick, onclientclick

how to add onclentclick and onclick events from code behind to image button. I wrote some code it shows confirm message for onclientclick event but not firing onclick event.

my code is as following..

```
ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
img.ID = "img1";
img.Visible = true;
img.OnClientClick = "alert(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete folder with files ?'));";
img.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(img_Click);
img.ImageUrl = "~/images/admin/remove.png";
```

Event's code is :

```
void img_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
 //code what i want to implement   
}
```

Comment: There is nothing on img_Click?

Comment: May be confirm is the cause of the problem. just remove the confirm in alert and check.

Answer (score 1):

change `OnClientClick` as bellow

```
   img.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete folder with files ?');";
```

Or you can add script in your aspx page as method and then call that from `OnClientClick`

```
img.OnClientClick ="ConfirmDelete()";


<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmDelete()
  {
      return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete folder with files ?');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: if onclientclick returns true again i want to click event for that from code behind but onclick event not firing

Comment: i want onclick event also if onclienclick return true i wrote event for onclick but its not firing

Answer (score 0):

I think the line you have written:

```
img.OnClientClick = "alert(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete folder with files ?'));";
```

Should be replaced with:

```
img.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete folder with files ?');";
```

as no need of alert for **confirm** box.

Comment: i want onclick event also if onclienclick return true i wrote event for onclick but its not firing – baby just now